# How to use IK library inside Python SMACH state (Python)?

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, smach, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create create complex behaviors using the [SMACH library](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) *(e.g. grasping an object, bipod walking, etc)*.

In order to maintain flexibility, inside my SMACH state machines, I've used parameterized states *(e.g. I have a MoveAlongPath state which I instantiate with a list of joint waypoints to produce different movements: lift leg, plant leg, etc).*

I want to use an inverse kinematics library inside a SMACH state *(e.g. Calculate IK)* to generate a list of waypoints (which will be passed on to instances of the Movement state).

I am interested in the [HEBI Robotics API](http://docs.hebi.us/#kinematics-2) and the [trac_ik library](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) - both of which are in C++.

---

**My question is:**
**What's the recommended ROS way to make calls to a C++ IK library from inside a Python SMACH state?**

*... Boost Python, C++ SimpleActionServer?*

---

edit:
trac_ik has a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/pull-requests/16/adding-a-python-wrapper-for-trac-ik-using/diff) for a python wrapper but it hasn't been merged in yet.
edit:
As of 2018/29/01

- trac_ik_python has been released.
- HEBI has announced a Python API for their [motors/kinematics library](http://docs.hebi.us/tools.html#python-api)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276772/how-to-use-ik-library-inside-python-smach-state-(python)?/) by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-30**:
Why delete the question? Have you solved it? If so, then please post an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-01-30**:
I didn't really solve the question as stated, but trac_ik_python has been released - eliminating the original need.
I have modified the question title, added my own answer, and undeleted the question as recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of 2018-01-04, trac_ik has swig based python wrapper [trac_ik_python](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/HEAD/trac_ik_python/)

As of [~2018-01-31](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-indigo-kinetic-and-lunar-2018-01-29/3834), this will be available in the ROS kinetic repository.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-trac-ik
```

or from source at https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik

---

Additionally, HEBI is developing a [Python API](http://docs.hebi.us/tools.html#python-api) and a [ROS API](http://docs.hebi.us/tools.html#ros-api) for their motors/kinematics library

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0